# Bitcoin Transaction using API with Custom Fees

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, transaction-fees, api, fee-estimation

I want to transfer Bitcoin from one individual address to another using API. But I want to set Transaction fees as per my requirement. So How can I do it ?

Right now I am using blockchain-transaction - npm api for transfer bitcoin from one address to another. So please shade some lights on this.

```
var bitcoinTransaction = require('bitcoin-transaction');
//Send all my money from wallet1 to wallet2 on the bitcoin testnet
var from = "mm3gdVh8n6YtcNyaTKYkveB6yTME7aDWNJ";
var to = "mgPUfqJk4X6gE4P5Do5RfpkTFsYmsSjCya";
var privKeyWIF = "cNZi8iySqBToXMpcsQaHKD5uv7HExBQJBSi4dTg3ZPaEzeNAzvbj";    //Private key in WIF form (Can generate this from bitcoinlib-js)
bitcoinTransaction.getBalance(from, { network: "testnet" }).then((balanceInBTC) => {
    return bitcoinTransaction.sendTransaction({
from: from,
to: to,
privKeyWIF: privKeyWIF,
btc: balanceInBTC,
network: "testnet"
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself but having a look through the documentation on blockchain-transaction - npm api it looks like you can query fees, under the advanced section:

> fees - Gets a list of current fees based on the BitCoin network going
>   rate.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcoin-transaction

Looks like you can select a 'fastest' option or others:

> Set the fee for the transaction. Can be either one of "fastest",
>   "halfHour" or "hour" in which case the actual fee numbers are fetched
>   from the fees provider. Or it can be just a plain number in which case
>   that will be used as the Fee per Byte value in Satoshis. It is
>   recommended to use one of the string aliases unless you know what you
>   are doing.

You might have to specify a feesProvider, not sure if they have a default selected when nothing set.

Comment: I have try it in my code but it's not working. It shows me same error.

First of all I try `Fees=3`(as integer) after that `Fees="3"`(as string) and also I have try for FeesProvider. but no luck.

Comment: "It is recommended to use one of the string aliases unless you know what you are doing."

Comment: "Can be either one of "fastest", "halfHour" or "hour" in which case the actual fee numbers are fetched from the fees provider."

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get answer for this question by surfing very much for this topic.

I found source code for transfer Bitcoin from one individual account to another.

"https://github.com/Blank101/bitcoin-transaction/blob/master/index.js"

and there I set feePerByte = 3 as per my requirement. So by set this Transaction fees My transaction does not deduct much more fees.